# GoDaddy Certificates API (customerID)

Tags: godaddy-api

Where can I find godaddy customerId in UUIDv4 for certificates api? I need customerId to retrieve my certificates list but there is no information in godaddy docs where to find this one.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who might be stuck with this:
You can use this endpoint `v1/shoppers/{shopperId}?includes=customerId`
And simply use your customer number (available on top left corner of page under your profile name) as shopperId - that was not obvious to me.

Comment: I get a 404 not found if i provide my shopperId.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your profile > view source code > find "customerId" tag > done.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, doing a GoDaddy Certificates integration for a customer, I only had the customer's API key and secret key available, but I still needed the UUIDv4 customerId.

I used a GET request to the `v1/certificates` endpoint to get the shopperId from inside one of the certificate metadata objects, then another GET request to `v1/shoppers/{shopperId}?includes=customerId`.

The response to the Shoppers API request provided the UUIDv4 `customerId` value, which finally allowed me to use the `v2/customers/{customerId}/certificates` endpoint.

Comment: The endpoint GET /v1/certificates does not seem to exist any more.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an extension to [Mark Miller's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69169102/1171762) comment, visualising what to expect and how the complete API call looks like (customerId is the last returned key-value pair; 12345678 in API call is your shopperId which you can find in GoDaddy's control panel):

https://api.godaddy.com/v1/shoppers/12345678?includes=customerId

```
{
    "shopperId": "12345678",
    "marketId": "en-GB",
    "email": “your@email.com",
    "externalId": null,
    "nameFirst": “Your”,
    "nameLast": “Name”,
    "customerId": “X-X-X-X-X”
}
```