# How do I use GoDaddy's v2 API?

Tags: godaddy-api

There are requests in GoDaddy's API [docs](https://developer.godaddy.com/doc) that are only available in the v2, so I'd like to use v2. However, I couldn't find any public information on any general differences between the versions or any migration instructions.

My attempts were unsuccessful for some time, mostly because of the error `{"code": "ERROR_INTERNAL", "message": "Not Found : Failed to get customer data for customerId or shopperId xxxxxxx"}`. 
 When using the same API key/secret and shopperId, the V1 requests all work, but none on the V2 work.

I noticed in the [certificates](https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/certificates) API docs (but is missing in the [domains](https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains) API docs) that `shopperId is not the same as customerId. shopperId is a number of max length 10 digits (ex: 1234567890) whereas customerId is a UUIDv4 (ex: 295e3bc3-b3b9-4d95-aae5-ede41a994d13)`. But it doesn't describe how to find the UUIDv4 customer ID.

Comment: how did you solve this? I am receiving the same error with v2. tried passing customerid too.

Comment: My problem was solved when I added a customerId (the trick was getting the customerId that looks like `295e3bc3-a3b9-4d95-aae5-edf41a994d13`, not the normal shopperId). See the answer posted below, and the answer [it links to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69169102/8909707).

If you have a customerId that does look like that being set, maybe you don't have access to that customer in some way? I can't remember how this works as I haven't touched the GoDaddy APIs in over a year.

Answer (score 0):

With help from [Mark Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9404659/mark-miller) and [Anton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16185533/anton), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69169102/8909707), I was able to find the customer Id with a request that looks like `v1/shoppers/{shopperId}?includes=customerId`. The query param is required in order to actually get the UUIDv4 in the response, which wasn't super obvious when looking at the v1 get shoppers documentation.