# How do I redeem a domain with GoDaddy's API?

Tags: godaddy-api

I have a subaccount that has a domain in the "redemption" state [after it expired](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/what-happens-when-my-domain-expires-609), and I would like to "redeem" it so I can renew it. From looking in the API [docs](https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains#/Domains/post_v2_customers__customerId__domains__domain__redeem), it is only available in the v2 API, and I was able to get started in the v2 API [with some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70026887/how-do-i-use-godaddys-v2-api). However, even with the correct UUIDv4 customer ID for the domain, I get the error: `{ "code": "ERROR_INTERNAL", "message": "Internal Server Error"}`

Answer (score 0):

The POST body is not labelled as required in the [docs](https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains#/Domains/post_v2_customers__customerId__domains__domain__redeem), but it is required. To get details on each of the fields, you need to click on the button (which is easy to miss) that switches between "Example Value" and "Model" ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D6fQ.png))